# Preload scripts not being executed in webview iframes

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, webview, electron

Webview tag that is present in the renderer process, somewhere in `<body>`:

```
<webview src="http://somewebpage.com" preload="somescript.js">
```

`somescript.js` is executed in somewebpage, but if somewebpage has `<iframe>`s in it, the script will not run in the iframe.

How can I make it run? And before any other script in the iframe?

I found this issue on github that seems related:
https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/19260
but it doesn't make any sense...

I tried adding `nodeintegrationinsubframes` and changing values from false to true

```
<webview src="somewebpage" preload="somescript.js" nodeintegrationinsubframes="false">
```

but it has no effect :(

Answer (score 4):

**main.js**

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 728,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,
        webviewTag: true,
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
```

**renderer**

```
<webview
            src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe"
            preload="./preload.js"
            style='width: 100%; height: 800px'
            nodeIntegrationInSubFrames
        />
```

**preload.js**

```
process.once("loaded", () => {
    alert(window.location);
});
```

You can specify where you are going to execute javascript based on the `window.location` This above code will show the locations of every sub iframes.

This works for me very well.

Comment: What is your electron version?

Comment: The latest stable one

Comment: I'm using v9.2.1

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( Do you see the alert twice ?

Comment: Well, before uploading the answer I always test myself.

Comment: @Alex please make sure if the preload script is being loaded correctly.

Comment: And are you using the latest Electron version?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problems with my project and updating the electron to the latest beta version solved for me.

I assume you know how to do this:

```
npm install electron@11.0.0-beta.6
```

You still have to consider the stability concerns of using a development version of the package.

Answer (score 1):

By scratching on `electron's` documentation perhaps this could be helpful as an alternative.

#### app.js

```
let win
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,
      webviewTag: true,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js') // Specifies a script that will be loaded before other scripts run in the page. This script will always have access to node APIs no matter whether node integration is turned on or off. The value should be the absolute file path to the script. When node integration is turned off, the preload script can reintroduce Node global symbols back to the global scope.
    }
  })
  ...
})
```

#### renderrer

```
<webview 
src="https://somewebpage.com" 
preload="./preload.js" 
nodeintegrationinsubframes>
```

#### preload.js

```
/* It can be used by the preload script to add removed Node global symbols back to the global scope when node integration is turned off */
const _setImmediate = setImmediate
const _clearImmediate = clearImmediate
process.once('loaded', () => {
  global.setImmediate = _setImmediate
  global.clearImmediate = _clearImmediate
})
```

My answer is based on the following resources:

- Electron Documentation:  [Tag](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#nodeintegrationinsubframes)
- Electron Documentation:
  [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions)
- Electron Documentation: [process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/process#event-loaded)
- Electron
  Documentation: [Web embeds in Electron - WebViews](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/web-embeds#webviews)
- Electron
  Documentation: [Preload Example](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/sandbox-option#preload)